# Add new event on new created element in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, append

I try to add event after click on button, who is created by append.

```
$("#panelEdycji").append("<div class='text-center'><button id='zamknijTo' type='button' class='buttons_close btn btn-info btn-xs'>"+ikona_powrot+"Powrót </button> </div>");
```

That work`s great, but now, I want to add event click in this:

```
("#zamknijTo" ).click(function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

But this not work, What I do wrong?

Comment: Assuming you just missed out the `$` at the beginning of your second code block when asking the question, that should work fine. Do you *already* have an element with that `id` value? Remember `id` values must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation -

```
$("#panelEdycji").on('click','#zamknijTo',function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

`----->`  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: No, the OP doesn't "need" to use delegation. The OP's code should work, the problem lies in something the OP hasn't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Since your element created dynamically to the DOM, the click event will not be available for these elements. In this case, event delegation will help you to attach that event.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click',"#zamknijTo" ,function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

Comment: To be useful, say *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am adding

Comment: Well, the answer should be complete and useful *before* you post it. What if you get called away? Your internet goes down? Etc. It's more important to post useful answers than to be first.

Comment: Separately: According to the OP's code, the element is already in the document, so delegation isn't *necessary*. (It may be desireable, but the OP's quoted code should work.)

Answer (score 0):

Try [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the element generated dynamically, And also you are missing `$`, may be a posting error, but double check again.

```
$("#panelEdycji").on("click","#zamknijTo",function(){
    alert("ok");
});
```

Comment: The OP's code should work, delegation may or may not be desireable, but not using it is not what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah. i realized that, May be the problem here is the `$` sign, OP need to double check it again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **on** keyword to bind the event of dynamically added element in DOM.

```
$("#zamknijTo" ).on("click",function(e){
    alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the on keyword to apply jquery code to the newly created element.

```
$('#zamknijTo').on( 'click',function(){
alert(1);
});
```

Comment: No, `.click(function() { })` is a shortcut for `.on("click", function() { })`. This changes nothing.

Comment: Well noted, Thank you :)